# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Hangfire error on replication

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, asp.net-core-2.0, hangfire

I using a kubernetes StatefulSet for a hangfire pod in gke kubernetes. It is working perfectly except when I make a replication. I get this exception due the Antiforgery token validation:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery[7]
>         An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could 
>       not be decrypted. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key 
>       {9f4f1619-10ff-4283-a529-eb48a0799815} was not found in the key ring.

Is there any solution please ?

Comment: Have you configured multile instances for asp.net core? As this [Data Protection and caching](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/web-farm?view=aspnetcore-2.1#data-protection-and-caching), you may consider [Azure Storage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#azure-storage) or [Redis](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#redis) as key storage providers.

Answer (score 1):

The response is to Persist DataProtection key to redis

```
var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost,password=password");

services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToStackExchangeRedis(redis, "DataProtection-Keys");
```